# Python: NoneType AttributeError when implementing priority queue with linked nodes

Tags: python, runtime-error, non-type

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, priority='L', next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.priority = priority
        self.next = next

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class P_Queue:
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        self.length = 0

    def enqueue(self, node):
        newNode = Node(node.data, node.priority)
        if (self.head == None):
            self.head = newNode
        elif (self.head and self.head.priority == 'L' and newNode.priority == 'H'):
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode
        elif (self.head and self.head.priority == 'H' and newNode.priority == 'H'):
            last = self.head
            while (last.next and last.next.priority == 'H'):
                last = last.next
            if (last.next and last.next.next):
                newNode.next = last.next.next
            last.next = newNode
        else:
            last = self.head
            while last.next:
                last = last.next
            last.next = newNode
        self.length += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        node = self.head
        print("next head: ")
        print(self.head.next)
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.length = self.length - 1
        return node

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.length==0

def main():
    node0 = Node(0, 'L')
    node1 = Node(1, 'H')
    node2 = Node(2, 'H')

    queue = P_Queue()

    queue.enqueue(node0)
    queue.enqueue(node1)
    queue.enqueue(node2)

    print(queue.dequeue())
    print(queue.dequeue())
    print(queue.dequeue())

main()
```

The problem occurs for the last line of the displayed code at the while statement in queue(), I get the error "'Nontype' object has no attribute property.", but only for queue(node1)

However, according to my print statements (output: H) for node0 = Node(0, 'H'), I clearly have a value of 'H' for that attribute (priority) and it does not contain a 'None' value so it's just mindboggling to me.

Please help... and if anyone has a good resource for learning how to implement a priority queue with a linked list for beginners that would be great too. Thank-you so much I'm dying here.

Traceback below:

```
next head: 2
1
next head: None
2
next head:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment1_3 queues.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "assignment1_3 queues.py", line 60, in main
    print(queue.dequeue())
  File "assignment1_3 queues.py", line 39, in dequeue
    print(self.head.next)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Can you add the traceback to your question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop works. You keep forwarding your `last = last.next` until you reach `NoneType`. Before you progressing your `last` to `last.next`, verify there is a node there. I've modified this part of your code:

```
    elif (self.head.priority == 'H' and newNode.priority == 'H'):
        last = self.head
        print(self.head.priority)
        print(last.priority)
        while last.priority == 'H' and last.next:  # <-- check last.next 
                                                         exists before pointing to it
            last = last.next
        if last.next and last.next.next:  # <-- same thing here
            newNode.next = last.next.next
        last.next = newNode
```

and this is the output:

```
>>> main()
H
H
```

Comment: Thank-you so much. I made the changes as you suggested but I'm encountering runtime errors for a particular set of inputs. I updated the code above could you take a look at it? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Actually nevermind I think I got it. Thank-you so much for your help!

Comment: @SifanXu  You welcome, glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it, thx

Comment: thanks I tried but unfortunately I don't have 15 rep. Sorry about that :( it says the vote is recorded but not publicly displayed